# reusing component instance in react render

Tags: reactjs

Parent class has several children components,  all the children are instantiated inside render method, so any change to  parent state will cause all the children to be re instantiated , everytime render is called react creates  new instance of children, there by loosing state of children, in order to reuse the child instance I tried retrieving child instance using parent.refs.childRef , but this gives me error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child

,  here is my code

```
placeHolderComponent(){
        let component;
        let palceHolderValue=this.state.uiState.placeHolder;
        let classInstance=this;
        if(palceHolderValue=='empty'){
            component=<EmptyComponent></EmptyComponent>
        }
        else if(palceHolderValue=='search'){
                component= classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent!=null?  classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent:    <GpSearch  ref="gpSearchComponent"/>
        }
        return component;
    }
```

here GpSearch Component is instantiated with a ref attribute , and code checks if parent.refs.childComponentRefId is not null then render that instance, instead a new instance. I am getting this error

> Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (.... If you
>   meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap
>   the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons

Answer (score 1):

> *"any change to parent state will cause all the children to be re instantiated"*

No, any change to parent state can cause a re-render of parent and its children. Child components are **not recreated**, but **re-rendered** (albeit you can avoid re-rendering of children with the life cycle hook `shouldComponentUpdate`).

> *"loosing state of children"*

again No. Children won't lose their internal state when the're re-rendered.

The error is presumably thrown by this line:

```
 component = classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent != null ?  classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent: <GpSearch  ref="gpSearchComponent"/>
```

because `classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent` is an object and as React complains "Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child".

```
    if(palceHolderValue=='empty'){
        component=<EmptyComponent></EmptyComponent>
    }
    else if(palceHolderValue=='search'){
            component= classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent!=null?  classInstance.refs.gpSearchComponent:    <GpSearch  ref="gpSearchComponent"/>
    }
    return component;
```

according to ^^ this code, I think you either render an `EmptyComponent` or `GpSearch` component. So whenever the `placeHolderValue` changes you unmount the currently re-rendered component. That is how your component are re-instantiated each time, and thus you lose internal state of child components.

An alternative approach is, you keep the state of children in your parent (as parent component's state) and pass it as props to children as required.